# TokuDB size_allocated vs size_in_use

Tags: mysql, database-administration, tokudb

Alhough TokuDB offers great compression, from what i see it wastes a lot of space by allocating a lot more than it actually needs.

I'm using the information_schema to get the size, as follows:

```
SELECT
    table_name, 
    table_dictionary_name, 
    round(bt_size_allocated/1024/1024,2) as size_allocated, 
    round(bt_size_in_use/1024/1024,2) as size_in_use
FROM
    information_schema.`TokuDB_fractal_tree_info`
```

and here is the result

```
+----------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
|     table      |     dictionary_name       | size_allocated  | size_in_use |
+----------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| c_tokudb_table | key-XID_id                | 875.43          | 411.59      |
| c_tokudb_table | key-operationId_timeStamp | 913.38          | 459.06      |
| c_tokudb_table | key-time_stamp            | 737.36          | 338.67      |
| c_tokudb_table | main                      | 3217.93         | 1505.58     |
| c_tokudb_table | status                    | 0.04            | 0.00        |
+----------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

as you can see `size_allocated` is basically doubled. The files on disk are just a bit more than size_allocated so reporting is good using information_schema.

I tried running optimize a few times but it doesn't help that much, sometimes it even increases. The only solution that seems to work is running an `ALTER TABLE`tbl`engine=tokudb` but it takes a lot of time because it completely rebuilds the table.

Does anyone know how to recover the unused space?

(running tokudb 5.6.27-76.0 on a percona mysql server)

Answer (score 1):

`optimize table` command should help to flush out deleted rows, thus free-up space, but this may also take a lot of time. You can try to adjust [tokudb_cleaner_period and tokudb_cleaner_iterations settings](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/tokudb/tokudb_variables.html) to enable more frequent cleaning of data.

Comment: On a new table with a lot of data and `size_allocated` being just 10% more than `size_in_use`, running `optimize table` actually increased the `size_allocated` by 80% while `size_in_use` remained the same. There were no deletes performed and the optimize statement executed in about 2 minutes.